# How to spring reseed cool season grass + pre-emergent herbicide

Tags: lawn, weed-control, weeds, lawn-repair

I did a bit of [lawn repair last Fall](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/55204/26690) in our front area, which was a reasonable success. I am thinking of doing the same to other parts of the lawn. I know that Fall is the best time for this kind of lawn repair in western Massachusetts, but the big patches of brown area (that used to be occupied by crabgrass) made me very much interested in trying something this Spring.

The timing seems tricky. If we put down the seeds now, then by the time they can be mowed two or three times, I am afraid that crabgrass will also sprout. If we apply [Scotts fertilizer with pre-emergent herbicide](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Scotts-Turf-Builder-Halts-Crabgrass-Preventer-with-Lawn-Food-40-05-lbs/20713587) now, then when will we be able to seed the new grass? How do people repair lawn in the Spring?

We probably should not have used the dethatcher, which managed to pull a lot of dead crabgrass out and left big patches of exposed soil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [Scotts Starter Fertilizer Plus Weed Preventer](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Scotts-Starter-Plus-Weed-Preventer-21-52-lb-5000-sq-ft-21-22-4-Lawn-Starter/4005779), which seems to have worked pretty well to prevent weeds as well as fertilizing the seeds.